# Is there an event triggered when dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, envdte, vs-extensibility

I am building a visual studio 2010 Add-in for internal use in my company.  I would like to customize the main window caption to display the name of the current start up project.  I can set the caption of the main window with the following code:

```
            DTE d = GlobalClass.dte2 as DTE;
        IntPtr hWnd = new System.IntPtr(d.MainWindow.HWnd);


        if (d.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects != null)
        {
            object[] sStartUpProject = (object[])d.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects;

            string Caption = d.MainWindow.Caption + "Current Project: " + (string)sStartUpProject[0];

            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, new IntPtr(0), Caption);
        }
```

I can fire this code whenever a window is created or activated, but this does not update the Caption if the user changes the startup project in the solution explorer (or my add-in) and doesn't move to another window in Visual Studio.  I would like the caption to update as soon as the change was made.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: I did not find a solution, but we stopped development on the add-in around this time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need subscribe to `IVsMonitorSelection` events and handle `SEID_StartupProject` in `OnElementValueChanged()`.

Check out this code, it's quite self-explaining:

https://bitbucket.org/thirteen/switchstartupproject/src/a80f0deb737c/SwitchStartupProject/SwitchStartupProjectPackage.cs